# Are there any ActionScript 3 components/UI optimised for use in Adobe AIR touch/mobile applications?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air, touch

I have been searching for about a week now and found such pure AS3 UI/components:

What I'm trying to create is (Adobe AIR mobile) options/settings menu for game and depending on the size/pixel density of a particular screen 
may require scrolling down options, mimicking the scrolling lists of Android with visual indicator of list location and the visual clue when reaching the end of the list
with the inertia too

MinimalComps (minimalcomps.com)

Razorberry (razorberry.com/blog/components/)

But they are all optimised for mouse clicks and use scrollbars as the interaction area for [example](http://www.riamore.com/content/RIAmore/Rich-Internet-Applications/YouKnits-designer/YouKnits-designer-app-for-Android)
(uses minimalcomps, try to use it in browser on mobile touchscreen, very fiddly to use, in fact had to zoom in just to get past the conditions screen(!!))

I've had no luck finding any information or tutorial to create menu system in Adobe AIR mobile in pure AS3 (it usually just links to Flex or AIR desktop applications)
I only found one example of game pure AS3 with source to show, http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/05/my_presentation_on_multiscreen_development.html
but it doesn't show you how to implement basic touch menus/UI or interface,

Comment: I would recommend going with Flex - it *is* an mobile-optimised UI framework. They've already put in the hard yards of getting the components working as you'd expect on mobile devices. Plus you're already using Air so I would expect that Flex should slot in fairly easily with that.

Comment: I should've mentioned I'm pretty much a beginner level with programming anyway(!!); so to use Flex I would have to look at the mxml (??) language to utilise the components/UI right??  I mean I am confused because searching came up with 'Flex Hero' and previous versions that led to obsolete links on adobe's pages, thanks for suggestion

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm using FlashDevelop so I followed tutorials in which the Flex SDK is installed first then the AIR SDK over that, so it means I can use Flex as is??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been meaning to give [mad components](http://code.google.com/p/mad-components/) a try, [they look very promising](http://madskool.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/madcomponents-wow/). Not sure if they'll solve your particular problem, but they do seem to outperform a similarly equipped Flex app (based on other developer's comments ;)

Comment: I've read numerous comments about Flex needing bigger size and processing for somewhat simple UI components (all I need; some 'scrollable lists' with toggle buttons and clear interface hierarchy) although of course being that Flex is fully customiseable and infinitely flexible and powerful.     It looks like mad-components even offer pure AS3 implemetation, thankyou!!

Answer (score 3):

Look at foxhole components :
[source](https://github.com/joshtynjala/foxhole-starling) and [example](http://flashtoolbox.com/foxhole-starling/examples/kitchen-sink/)

And You can also look at this project i working on , its extension for MinimalComps that works like Flex display system and have databinding . With little style work and extend few components You can use it on touchscreens.

source: https://github.com/turbosqel/Extended-MinimalComps
example: http://turbosqel.pl/ExMinimalComps/simple/

Comment: thanks, so for the Foxhole-starling I need to include Starling, GTween and as3-signals in my FlashDevelop Classpaths along with the Foxhole-starling library, I assume that's how it works.    Your example of Extended-MinimalComps is really cool !!

Comment: I spend some time on this components , im looking for usefull solutions for future UI frameworks. With little time it should be ready to implement in touch screen.

Answer (score 0):

[Feathers UI](http://feathersui.com/) powered by Starling (fully GPU-rendered UI)

Its officially supported by Adobe, 100% open source and skinnable. See [apps and games](http://feathersui.com/showcase/) that use it for their UI. Docs are [here](http://feathersui.com/help/).

This is the recommended method as of 2014-2015. For example, foxhole components is now depreciated in favor of Feathers.